# PHPSpreadsheet - writing htmlentities / convert into correspoding chars

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSPreadsheet 1.6.0 to export data from Neo4J to an Excel File.

The write code is

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A1',$string);
```

This works well as long as I do not have HTML entities. For Neo4J Reasons I store some text in HTML entities like

```
8&quot; ID x 12&quot;
```

which reads for humans

```
8" ID x 12"
```

(the quotes are part of the string and important for the reader as it is a measurement (inch) and can't be skipped.

I tried to use

```
html_entity_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

to produce a clean output in the cell of the excel sheet. The output on the screen is ok when printed within a php file showing as expected

```
8" ID x 12"
```

In the Excelfile I always get

```
8&quot; ID x 12&quot;
```

no matter how I format the string or change the coding (tried also without any changes). Anyone has a tip how to get the original characters instead of the html entities?

***Further investigation:***

When I enter text instead of a variable like

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( 'A1',
            html_entity_decode('8&quot; ID x 2&quot;',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') );
```

this works like a charme, trying the same with a variable like $string where as

```
$string = '8&quot; ID x 2&quot;'

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 
            html_entity_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')
            );
```

generates again the output

```
8&quot; ID x 12&quot;
```

inside the excel cell. For a reason I cannot figure out this function doesnt work with strings?

*** ADDED ***

It doesn't matter also if I combine the string outside the spreadsheet-action like

```
$itemShort = html_entity_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

and using then

```
                $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('C'.$i,$itemShort)
                        ;
```

No matter, a text constant is working well, a variable not.

Comment: Your code works fine even with the variable $string. Can you re-check or post some extra piece of code?

Comment: Sorry coming back so late, other things... I re-checked all, still a text works fine, the moment I replaced the string constant with a variable it gives me the same behaviour. I work now with a str_replace afterwards but this is just a workaround. I have no idea why using a variable fails. I also tried to combine the string extra and insert than this string into the spreadsheet-action, getting same error. This is valid for all PC I use so I dare to exclude a local problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case using either the
**constant string**
`html_entity_decode('8&quot; ID x 2&quot;',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))`
or
**variable**
`$string = '8&quot; ID x 2&quot;'`
`html_entity_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')`
both of them didn't work.
Finally I just set the cell value with
`$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'replace_this_string');`
then after loading the html with
`$html = $this->load->view('folder/view', $data, TRUE);`
then before rendering the pdf with dompdf, i replace the string with
`$new_html = str_replace('replace_this_string','"', $html);`

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used HTML entities in this manner:

```
$yAxisLabel = new Title(html_entity_decode('Temp (&deg;C)',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still unsure how to work with this class 'Title' - do you have a link to an explanation? Using the code throws an unknown class error for me. Do I need to include something or is 'Title' somewhere defined? Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I can add, is the manual: [link](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.2.1/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Chart.html)

Comment: Thank you, that is always helpful. I'll have a peek into it.